# get key value from object and add it to another object matching nested value

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

I'm working with angular and lodash.
I have two array of object. What I'm trying to do is to get the `vehicle` key value from second and add it to each object of `consegne` inside a new key `veicolo`. My goal is to check if inside `steps.location` of `route` there is `lat_cliente` and `long_cliente` from `consegne` and if it true get the correspondent `vehicle` key value from `route` and add it to every object of `consenge`, so at the end I can know which delivery is assign to what vehicle.

my arrays:

**consegne:**

```
consegne = {
    "2020-06-03 14:30:00": [
      {
        "max(a.dataora_ord)": "2020-06-03T11:43:12.508Z",
        id_ordine: 100002,
        id_cliente: "2199",
        id_negozio: "1",
        numero_prodotti: 1,
        importo: 11.3,
        indirizzo_cliente: "VIA BENEDETTO CROCE 1 GUBBIO",
        lat_cliente: 43.3422695,
        long_cliente: 12.5914081,
        lat_negozio: 43.1070321,
        long_negozio: 12.402996209906487
      }
    ],
    "2020-06-04 14:30:00": [
      {
        "max(a.dataora_ord)": "2020-06-04T11:52:38.099Z",
        id_ordine: 100003,
        id_cliente: "2197",
        id_negozio: "1",
        numero_prodotti: 3,
        importo: 67.64,
        indirizzo_cliente: "VIA PIAVE 1 SAN GEMINI",
        lat_cliente: 42.6103269,
        long_cliente: 12.5503077,
        lat_negozio: 43.1070321,
        long_negozio: 12.402996209906487
      }
    ],
    "2020-06-01 11:30:00": [
      {
        "max(a.dataora_ord)": "2020-06-01T08:27:28.467Z",
        id_ordine: 100000,
        id_cliente: "2194",
        id_negozio: "1",
        numero_prodotti: 2,
        importo: 8.71,
        indirizzo_cliente: "PIAZZA BRANDUCCI 1 FOLIGNO",
        lat_cliente: 42.95726165,
        long_cliente: 12.70359885,
        lat_negozio: 43.1070321,
        long_negozio: 12.402996209906487
      }
    ],
    "2020-05-27 10:30:00": [
      {
        "max(a.dataora_ord)": "2020-05-27T07:44:00.000Z",
        id_ordine: 99999,
        id_cliente: "2210",
        id_negozio: "1",
        numero_prodotti: 5,
        importo: 41.79,
        indirizzo_cliente: "LOCALITA' ARVELLO 1 FOLIGNO",
        lat_cliente: 43.0324959,
        long_cliente: 12.8516742,
        lat_negozio: 43.1070321,
        long_negozio: 12.402996209906487
      }
    ],
    ...
  };
```

**route:**

```
  route = [
    {
      vehicle: 1,
      cost: 9438,
      delivery: [1],
      amount: [1],
      pickup: [0],
      service: 420,
      duration: 9438,
      waiting_time: 0,
      distance: 145681,
      steps: [
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.5503077, 42.6103269],
          job: 0,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [0],
          arrival: 1590071446,
          duration: 4766,
          distance: 73086
        }
      ],
      geometry:
        ""
    },
    {
      vehicle: 1,
      cost: 9438,
      delivery: [1],
      amount: [1],
      pickup: [0],
      service: 420,
      duration: 9438,
      waiting_time: 0,
      distance: 145681,
      steps: [
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.5503077, 42.6103269],
          job: 0,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [0],
          arrival: 1590071446,
          duration: 4766,
          distance: 73086
        }
      ],
      geometry:
        ""
    },
    {
      vehicle: 1,
      cost: 6448,
      delivery: [1],
      amount: [1],
      pickup: [0],
      service: 420,
      duration: 6448,
      waiting_time: 0,
      distance: 81974,
      steps: [
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.5914081, 43.3422695],
          job: 0,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [0],
          arrival: 1590069911,
          duration: 3231,
          distance: 40076
        }
      ],
      geometry:
        ""
    },
    {
      vehicle: 1,
      cost: 5066,
      delivery: [1],
      amount: [1],
      pickup: [0],
      service: 420,
      duration: 5066,
      waiting_time: 0,
      distance: 73636,
      steps: [
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.70359885, 42.95726165],
          job: 0,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [0],
          arrival: 1590069018,
          duration: 2338,
          distance: 36148
        }
      ],
      geometry:
        ""
    },
    {
      vehicle: 1,
      cost: 8824,
      delivery: [2],
      amount: [2],
      pickup: [0],
      service: 840,
      duration: 8824,
      waiting_time: 0,
      distance: 137129,
      steps: [
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.7224235, 42.9327554],
          job: 1,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [1],
          arrival: 1590069262,
          duration: 2582,
          distance: 42641
        },
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.3291318, 43.305996],
          job: 0,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [0],
          arrival: 1590073531,
          duration: 6431,
          distance: 102982
        }
      ],
      geometry:
        ""
    },
    {
      vehicle: 1,
      cost: 1562,
      delivery: [1],
      amount: [1],
      pickup: [0],
      service: 420,
      duration: 1562,
      waiting_time: 0,
      distance: 16290,
      steps: [
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.4418193, 43.133661],
          job: 4,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [0],
          arrival: 1590067508,
          duration: 828,
          distance: 8181
        }
      ],
      geometry:
        ""
    },
    {
      vehicle: 2,
      cost: 17059,
      delivery: [4],
      amount: [4],
      pickup: [0],
      service: 1680,
      duration: 17059,
      waiting_time: 0,
      distance: 245267,
      steps: [
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.5914081, 43.3422695],
          job: 3,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [3],
          arrival: 1590069911,
          duration: 3231,
          distance: 40076
        },
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.5407404, 43.1424873],
          job: 1,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [2],
          arrival: 1590072736,
          duration: 5636,
          distance: 74350
        },
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.538253, 43.1009005],
          job: 2,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [1],
          arrival: 1590073639,
          duration: 6119,
          distance: 80353
        },
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.6476612, 42.5602885],
          job: 0,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [0],
          arrival: 1590079503,
          duration: 11563,
          distance: 161286
        }
      ],
      geometry:
        ""
    },
    {
      vehicle: 1,
      cost: 4730,
      delivery: [1],
      amount: [1],
      pickup: [0],
      service: 420,
      duration: 4730,
      waiting_time: 0,
      distance: 66605,
      steps: [
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.3291318, 43.305996],
          job: 0,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [0],
          arrival: 1590069017,
          duration: 2337,
          distance: 32457
        }
      ],
      geometry:
        ""
    },
    {
      vehicle: 1,
      cost: 6150,
      delivery: [1],
      amount: [1],
      pickup: [0],
      service: 420,
      duration: 6150,
      waiting_time: 0,
      distance: 90278,
      steps: [
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.7592267, 43.0696255],
          job: 0,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [0],
          arrival: 1590069655,
          duration: 2975,
          distance: 45300
        }
      ],
      geometry:
        ""
    },
    {
      vehicle: 1,
      cost: 2947,
      delivery: [1],
      amount: [1],
      pickup: [0],
      service: 420,
      duration: 2947,
      waiting_time: 0,
      distance: 31642,
      steps: [
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.517752, 43.155195],
          job: 0,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [0],
          arrival: 1590068153,
          duration: 1473,
          distance: 15811
        }
      ],
      geometry:
        ""
    },
    {
      vehicle: 1,
      cost: 12378,
      delivery: [4],
      amount: [4],
      pickup: [0],
      service: 1680,
      duration: 12378,
      waiting_time: 0,
      distance: 178809,
      steps: [
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.7020796, 42.9564996],
          job: 11,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [3],
          arrival: 1590069028,
          duration: 2348,
          distance: 36221
        },
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.7020796, 42.9564996],
          job: 10,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [2],
          arrival: 1590069448,
          duration: 2348,
          distance: 36221
        },
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.649205, 42.5624235],
          job: 8,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [1],
          arrival: 1590074020,
          duration: 6500,
          distance: 91183
        },
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.5471666, 42.6143734],
          job: 4,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [0],
          arrival: 1590075752,
          duration: 7812,
          distance: 107094
        }
      ],
      geometry:
        ""
    },
    {
      vehicle: 2,
      cost: 8513,
      delivery: [4],
      amount: [4],
      pickup: [0],
      service: 1680,
      duration: 8513,
      waiting_time: 0,
      distance: 117438,
      steps: [
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.7037126, 42.9575853],
          job: 0,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [3],
          arrival: 1590069044,
          duration: 2364,
          distance: 36287
        },
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.7592267, 43.0696255],
          job: 6,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [2],
          arrival: 1590070831,
          duration: 3731,
          distance: 53447
        },
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.7803655, 43.2322369],
          job: 5,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [1],
          arrival: 1590072722,
          duration: 5202,
          distance: 74454
        },
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.7860033, 43.2321763],
          job: 1,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [0],
          arrival: 1590073340,
          duration: 5400,
          distance: 75854
        }
      ],
      geometry:
        ""
    },
    {
      vehicle: 3,
      cost: 11843,
      delivery: [4],
      amount: [4],
      pickup: [0],
      service: 1680,
      duration: 11843,
      waiting_time: 0,
      distance: 168496,
      steps: [
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.191765, 43.5116042],
          job: 2,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [3],
          arrival: 1590070697,
          duration: 4017,
          distance: 60993
        },
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.1659394, 43.5551518],
          job: 9,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [2],
          arrival: 1590071741,
          duration: 4641,
          distance: 67362
        },
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.5263973, 43.105579],
          job: 7,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [1],
          arrival: 1590076781,
          duration: 9261,
          distance: 136495
        },
        {
          type: "job",
          location: [12.4302894, 43.0265033],
          job: 3,
          service: 420,
          waiting_time: 0,
          load: [0],
          arrival: 1590078466,
          duration: 10526,
          distance: 152845
        }
      ],
      geometry:
        ""
    }
  ];
```

in route array

array of objects and I'm trying to get object index checking nested array value inside it with lodash (even if also a solution with vanilla js is accept)

this is what I've tried:

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as _ from "lodash";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;


  ngOnInit() {
    const coord = [];
    _.forOwn(this.consegne,
      coordinatePoi => _.map(coordinatePoi,
        latLong => coord.push(_.at(latLong, ['long_cliente', 'lat_cliente'])))
    )

    coord.forEach(co => {
      const f = _.filter(this.route,
        {
          steps: [{location: co}]
        }
      );

      if(f[0] && f[0].vehicle) {
        _.forOwn(this.consegne, clienti => {_.forEach(clienti, c => c['veicolo'] = f[0].vehicle); console.log(this.consegne)})
      }
    })
  }
}
```

this is my partial success, but I think I'm missing something:

[image]

the final result would be:

```
consegne = {
    ...

    "2020-05-20 16:30:00": [
      {
        "max(a.dataora_ord)": "2020-05-20T13:59:03.000Z",
        id_ordine: 20,
        id_cliente: "2258",
        id_negozio: "1",
        numero_prodotti: 5,
        importo: 35.19,
        indirizzo_cliente: "CORSO NUOVO 1 FOLIGNO",
        lat_cliente: 42.9575853,
        long_cliente: 12.7037126,
        lat_negozio: 43.1070321,
        long_negozio: 12.402996209906487,
        veicolo: 1 // for example
      },
      {
        "max(a.dataora_ord)": "2020-05-20T13:39:54.000Z",
        id_ordine: 18,
        id_cliente: "2216",
        id_negozio: "1",
        numero_prodotti: 11,
        importo: 76.52,
        indirizzo_cliente: "VIA NUCCI 1 GUALDO TADINO",
        lat_cliente: 43.2321763,
        long_cliente: 12.7860033,
        lat_negozio: 43.1070321,
        long_negozio: 12.402996209906487,
        veicolo: 1 // for example
      },
      {
        "max(a.dataora_ord)": "2020-05-20T13:54:50.000Z",
        id_ordine: 15,
        id_cliente: "2302",
        id_negozio: "1",
        numero_prodotti: 12,
        importo: 103.31,
        indirizzo_cliente: "VIA ANNA GRAZIANI 1 TORGIANO",
        lat_cliente: 43.0265033,
        long_cliente: 12.4302894,
        lat_negozio: 43.1070321,
        long_negozio: 12.402996209906487,
        veicolo: 2 // for example
      },
      {
        "max(a.dataora_ord)": "2020-05-20T13:11:38.000Z",
        id_ordine: 17,
        id_cliente: "2193",
        id_negozio: "1",
        numero_prodotti: 7,
        importo: 64.52,
        indirizzo_cliente: "PIAZZA VITTORIO VENETO - SELCI LAMA 1 SAN GIUSTINO",
        lat_cliente: 43.5116042,
        long_cliente: 12.191765,
        lat_negozio: 43.1070321,
        long_negozio: 12.402996209906487,
        veicolo: 3 // for example
      },
      {
        "max(a.dataora_ord)": "2020-05-20T13:59:10.000Z",
        id_ordine: 13,
        id_cliente: "2271",
        id_negozio: "1",
        numero_prodotti: 15,
        importo: 92.12,
        indirizzo_cliente: "VIA FLAMINIA NORD 1 VALTOPINA",
        lat_cliente: 43.0696255,
        long_cliente: 12.7592267,
        lat_negozio: 43.1070321,
        long_negozio: 12.402996209906487,
        veicolo: 1 // for example
      },
      {
        "max(a.dataora_ord)": "2020-05-20T13:56:03.000Z",
        id_ordine: 12,
        id_cliente: "2224",
        id_negozio: "1",
        numero_prodotti: 18,
        importo: 142.17,
        indirizzo_cliente: "VIA GIUSEPPE LUCANTONI 1 GUALDO TADINO",
        lat_cliente: 43.2322369,
        long_cliente: 12.7803655,
        lat_negozio: 43.1070321,
        long_negozio: 12.402996209906487
        veicolo: 1 // for example
      },
      {
        "max(a.dataora_ord)": "2020-05-20T13:40:26.000Z",
        id_ordine: 14,
        id_cliente: "2266",
        id_negozio: "1",
        numero_prodotti: 15,
        importo: 110.19,
        indirizzo_cliente: "PIAZZA PALAZZO VECCHIO 1 SAN GEMINI",
        lat_cliente: 42.6143734,
        long_cliente: 12.5471666,
        lat_negozio: 43.1070321,
        long_negozio: 12.402996209906487,
        veicolo: 2 // for example
      },
      {
        "max(a.dataora_ord)": "2020-05-20T13:04:37.000Z",
        id_ordine: 5,
        id_cliente: "2485",
        id_negozio: "1",
        numero_prodotti: 7,
        importo: 35.76,
        indirizzo_cliente: "CORSO VECCHIO 133 TERNI",
        lat_cliente: 42.5624235,
        long_cliente: 12.649205,
        lat_negozio: 43.1070321,
        long_negozio: 12.402996209906487
        veicolo: 3 // for example
      },
      {
        "max(a.dataora_ord)": "2020-05-20T13:58:11.000Z",
        id_ordine: 3,
        id_cliente: "2260",
        id_negozio: "1",
        numero_prodotti: 16,
        importo: 95.31,
        indirizzo_cliente: "VIA LICINIO REFICE-PETRIGNANO 1 ASSISI",
        lat_cliente: 43.105579,
        long_cliente: 12.5263973,
        lat_negozio: 43.1070321,
        long_negozio: 12.402996209906487,
        veicolo: 1 // for example
      },
      ...
    ],

    ...
```

how can achive this?

this is my stackblitz:

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-blpado)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
        const vehcord=[]
route.forEach(x=>{
    for(let i=0;i<x.steps.length;i++){
    vehcord.push({vehicle:x.vehicle,location:x.steps[i].location})
    }})

for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(consegne)) {
    vehcord.forEach(vkey=>{
                value.forEach(x=>{
            if(x.long_cliente==vkey.location[0] && x.lat_cliente==vkey.location[1])
                  x.veicolo = vkey.vehicle
                })

      })
  }
  console.log(consegne)
```

Comment: thanks for your response, your solution quite working. It take the vehicle key only for first object entries, not for each. this is a stackblitx with your solution [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-vehicle), how can it work for each? thanks.

Comment: I have tested the code and it works you can check it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sven07/dnvhmuyL/). it will only add vehicle id if client  lat and long matches

Comment: strange, your work, but if you check my stakblitz [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/get-vehicle) and check in the console the array with 12 object, it add vehicle only to first object and not for the other, you can kindly check the stackblitz, if you can? I could help me a lot. thanks

Comment: i have updated the code can you try it now and let me know if it works

Comment: I have noticed  in your stackblitz that your `consegne` is nested i made the code based on the snippet you pasted here which is not nested , However I have adjusted the code now and tested it with the full data from your stackblitz and it works

Comment: many many thanks, now the snippet works. thanks for your disponibility.